# How to import a OC Pod directly in a Swift workspace

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

My Swift project has a pod wrote by Objective-C, and if I want use it, I have to make a Bridge-file.

Is there other better idea to import directly like this `import MYPOD`, just like import a Swift Pod.

Comment: No, to use Obj-C code in your Swift project you must have a Bridging-Header file

Comment: what if I make a Swift Pod including a Objective-C framework? Can I also make a Bridging-Header file?